# Is Ruby 1.9.3 supported on Mac OS? Or should I stick to 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-1.9.3

Is Ruby 1.9.3 supported on Mac OS? Or should I stick to 1.8.7? I am new to OS X and am setting up my Ruby development environment.

Comment: +1ing because it's not as stupid a question as some people think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted as well. This is a good question.

I run Ruby 1.9.3 for almost all my development work. I'd highly recommend using it.

Ruby 1.8.7 is older, slower and is running out of time for support.

I'd also recommend doing all installation of Ruby on your machine using RVM (The Ruby Version Manager). Here's the link to install it:

https://rvm.io//rvm/install/

Once you have RVM installed (the steps on its web page are good), then type the following to install Ruby 1.9.3:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

This will bring the latest version of Ruby 1.9.3 down and install it on your machine for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can install it from [source](https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/) or with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), or use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io//) to manage multiple Ruby versions.

Comment: Downvoting because it's not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, no. So I'm +1ing your question which currently has two downvotes.

According to the Ruby's wiki page on [Supported Platforms](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/SupportedPlatforms), OS X is not "Supported", but is merely "Best Effort" for both Ruby 1.9.3, and Ruby 1.9.1. Ruby 1.9.3 has no "Supported" platforms, and Ruby 1.9.1 only has Debian GNU/Linux 4.0 on IA32 supported.

However, Ruby 1.8.7 will soon reach its end of life as far as the [MRI Ruby team is concerned](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4996), and I wouldn't count on Apple doing much maintenance of Ruby 1.8.7. So use 1.9.3 anyway.

Comment: +1 Interesting. That page is a bit out-of-date though, clang/llvm is officially supported as of 1.9.3-p125. I know `make test` passes on OS X 10.7, but I haven't recently tried `make test-all`—not sure how different they are. Really interesting only 1.9.2 on 32-bit Debian is officially supported.

Comment: I learnt that I must have installed xcode before installing ruby.. info for new Mac users